# JS replace hashtag with slash

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hashtag, slash

Im wondering how do I replace a hashtag with a slash in the URL with Javascript or Jquery.

Example:

```
www.mysite.com/service#new
```

To:

```
www.mysite.com/service/new
```

Is this possible? I really can´t figure it out.

Greetings!

Comment: Where is the URL itself? On an `a` tag?

Comment: Yes it is on a <a> tag

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do this:

```
var url = "www.mysite.com/service#new";
url = url.replace('#', '/');
```

Or if you're trying to manipulate DOM elements directly, something like this should work:

```
$('a').each(function(i, e) {
    e.href = e.href.replace('#', '/');
});
```

Comment: Yeah Im trying to manipulate the DOM. If I try your code I only get a 404 Not Found. But it changes the # to / in the url.

Comment: @MrCaps Well, that's not a JavaScript issue then. If you change the URL, there's no guarantee that the server will accept the new URL.

Comment: Yeah maby, but is it possible to change this with htaccess?

Comment: @MrCaps The `#` portion of the URL won't be sent to the server. So you could use my code to modify the URL, then handle the *new* URL with a `mod_rewrite` rule. Without more info it's hard to say what the best course of action would be, but that's well beyond the scope of this question. I'd recommend you open a new question describing the specific problem you're having.